# Looping through two dimensional arrays based on conditions

Tags: excel, vba, loops, multidimensional-array

I am trying to loop through a two dimensional array based on a few conditions. I think I must have my syntax wrong because my conditions are not triggering the new loop (through the array of dates). This new loop, will test whether or not the user input date ("lastdate") =  UACFArray(l, 0) and if not to find whether or not that date is in between the values stored in UACFArray(l, 0) & UACFArray(0, m) and if so use the next position in that array(UACFArray(l+1, 0)/UACFArray(0, m+1).

Some helpful information before you look through everything:

a() is the original array in the original loop (loop i that is) that this is a part of. this loop is stuck at the very end of loop  i, so that it checks for this last. loop i begins with a case select statement for each step in a(). I stuck this loop at the end (of loop i) to override the previous values if the conditions are met.

If this is overall sloppy and just plain bad, please feel free to suggest best practices approaches as I would love to learn better ways of thinking about these things.

For example: User input is 1/3/15 (and since the code says to take lastdate+7 for the check), the conditions do not trigger the loop to check whether or not that 1) 1/3/15 doesnt match UACFArray(l, 0) nor does it check that its is in between UACFArray(l, 0) & UACFArray(0, m). the output is that of the original arguments in the case select.

Sample Code:

```
UACFArray(0, 0) = #1/6/2015#: UACFArray(0, 1) = #2/3/2015#
UACFArray(1, 0) = #1/20/2015#: UACFArray(1, 1) = #2/17/2015#
UACFArray(2, 0) = #2/10/2015#: UACFArray(2, 1) = #3/10/2015#
UACFArray(3, 0) = #2/24/2015#: UACFArray(3, 1) = #3/24/2015#
UACFArray(4, 0) = #3/17/2015#: UACFArray(4, 1) = #4/14/2015#
UACFArray(5, 0) = #3/31/2015#: UACFArray(5, 1) = #4/28/2015#
UACFArray(6, 0) = #4/21/2015#: UACFArray(6, 1) = #5/19/2015#
UACFArray(7, 0) = #5/5/2015#: UACFArray(7, 1) = #6/2/2015#
    If CheckBox = True And (ComboBox = "Text1" Or ComboBox = "Text2") And i = a(0) Then
        For l = LBound(UACFArray, 1) To UBound(UACFArray, 1)
            For m = LBound(UACFArray, 2) To UBound(UACFArray, 2)
                If (LastDate + 7) <> UACFArray(l, 0) And (LastDate + 7) > UACFArray(l, 0) And (LastDate + 7) < UACFArray(0, m) Then
                    BlcokStart = UACFArray(l + 1, 0)
                    BlockEnd = UACFArray(0, m + 1)
                End If
            Next m
        Next l
    ElseIF ComboBox = "Text1" Or ComboBox = "Text2" Then
        For l = LBound(UACFArray, 1) To UBound(UACFArray, 1)
                If UACFArray(l, 0) = BlcokStart Then
                    For m = LBound(UACFArray, 2) To UBound(UACFArray, 2)
                        BlockEnd = UACFArray(l, m)
                        a(i) = BlcokStart & " & " & BlockEnd
                        BlcokStart = UACFArray(l + 1, m)
                    Next m
                End If
        Next l
    End If
```

Comment: Note that the changes I made in editing make it clearer how the logic of your program branches - keeping each sub-branch one indent further than the branch above allows you to look down the path to see how everything is nested together. This is VBA standard practice, and more or less mirrors practices in other languages.

Comment: Also - your question is not well worded - you use internal jargon referring to variable and function names in your question, which is not initially clear. Some examples of inputs and outputs would help show the logic of your program.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your syntax is incorrect, you need control.value in order to check what is written in a combobox.
Example:
ElseIF ComboBox = "Text1" Or ComboBox = "Text2" Then

should be:
ElseIF ComboBox.Value = "Text1" Or ComboBox.Value = "Text2" Then

Also I would like to point out that you check the condition "checkbox has been checked by the user" with the line

checkbox.value = -1 for checked and

checkbox.value = 0 for unchecked.

(This is really counterintuitive, I know.)

The code "If checkbox = true then ..." doesn't cause an error, but it's not what you are looking for I assume.

Comment: Ah I forgot to include .value when I put this in here. However, the true/false evaluation of checkboxes is correct (especially if you gave your checkbox a custom name).